# show a system tray icon for all users on a server

Tags: powershell

I added a piece of code to my script that displays a system tray icon during the run of the script (around 3-5 hours).

I would like for other users who log into that server to be able to see that icon (which means the script is still running) and thus wont run the script again.

how can this be done?

(this is the code snip that shows the system tray icon):

```
$code = @"
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace System
{
public class IconExtractor
{

 public static Icon Extract(string file, int number, bool largeIcon)
 {
  IntPtr large;
  IntPtr small;
  ExtractIconEx(file, number, out large, out small, 1);
  try
  {
   return Icon.FromHandle(largeIcon ? large : small);
  }
  catch
  {
   return null;
  }

 }
 [DllImport("Shell32.dll", EntryPoint = "ExtractIconExW", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
 private static extern int ExtractIconEx(string sFile, int iIndex, out IntPtr piLargeVersion, out IntPtr piSmallVersion, int amountIcons);

}
}
'@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $code -ReferencedAssemblies System.Drawing

[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
$objNotifyIcon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
$objNotifyIcon.Icon = [System.IconExtractor]::Extract("shell32.dll", 24, $true) 
$objNotifyIcon.Text = "Script is running..."
$objNotifyIcon.Visible = $True
```

Comment: For that, you'll want to write a Windows Service application that actually does the work on behalf of the users, then start a hidden GUI application in the interactive session on logon that can communicate with the service to allow the users to either run the script or display that it's currently running another script, via the system tray icon

Comment: thanks for the idea. however im afraid this will complicate the script (which is rather simple) so i will ask, how will you approach the issue itself? (other users who log into this server need to know the script is running instead of running it once more)

Comment: That _would_ be my approach. You could also use a global [mutex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex) to detect whether another process on the machine is already running the script and then exit instead of going ahead